# PDF Attachment send by email and become a PDF.HTML

Tags: pdf, massemailmessage

I'm sending a attachment by email as a PDF. Not sure how and when it's happening, but sometimes it seems to **change the extension** of my pdf to **pdf.html**. It used to work perfectly before without to specify the contentType, just by mentioning .pdf in the fileName. I tried to add the contentType, but doesn't change anything. Here is a piece of the code I'm using:

```
Attachment att = [select id, body from Attachment where ParentId = :parentId];
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment emailFileAttachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
emailFileAttachment.setFileName('InvoiceXXXXXX.pdf');
emailFileAttachment.setContentType('application/pdf');
emailFileAttachment.setBody(att.Body);
emailFileAttachments.add(emailFileAttachment);
...
singleEmailMessage.setFileAttachments(emailFileAttachments);
...
emails.add(singleEmailMessage);
....
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
```

Anyone has ever got the same problem before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Salesforce converts attachment to html links when **total size exceeds 3Mb**. This is very annoying.

[Source 1](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ghJUAAY)

[Source 2](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004470&language=en_US)

Comment: Is it applicable to Apex email also, or only out of box emails?

Comment: I got the problem with Apex email only, not sure if it's the same with email workflow but I believe it's the case for every type of SFDC emails

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, it's still an issue in Spring 17 (API 39)